# How would I make the button hide the incomplete tasks

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

This is the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zxo35mts/1/

Essentially I'm trying to make the button hide all incomplete tasks when clicked and show them again when clicked again yet i have no idea what to do

```
<div id="root">

    <h1>
        All Tasks
    </h1>

    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task.description"></li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="hideIncompleteTasks">show only completed</button>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
    new Vue({

        el: "#root",

        data: {

            tasks: [

                { description: "go to the store", completed: true },
                { description: "finish screencast", completed: false },
                { description: "make donation", completed: false },
                { description: "clear inbox", completed: false },
                { description: "make dinner ", completed: false },
                { description: "clean room", completed: true },

            ]

        },
        methods: {

            hideIncompleteTasks() {
                if (!this.tasks.completed) {

                }
            }

        },

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another property called `showCompleted` which could be updated by the button click event, then add another computed property called `shownTasks` based on the first property :

```js
    new Vue({

        el: "#root",

        data: {

            tasks: [

                { description: "go to the store", completed: true },
                { description: "finish screencast", completed: false },
                { description: "make donation", completed: false },
                { description: "clear inbox", completed: false },
                { description: "make dinner ", completed: false },
                { description: "clean room", completed: true },

            ],
          showCompleted:false

        },
        computed:{
          shownTasks(){ return this.showCompleted?this.tasks.filter(task=>task.completed):this.tasks;}
        },
        methods: {

            hideIncompleteTasks() {
               this.showCompleted=!this.showCompleted
            }

        },

    })
```

then render the `shownTasks` like :

```html
 <ul>
        <li v-for="task in shownTasks" v-text="task.description"></li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="hideIncompleteTasks">show only completed</button>
```

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain how the changes you made work? so i can understand and not just copy you

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: why do we need a "showCompleted" property? also what is "computed: {}"

Comment: `showCompleted` is a property that we could toggle it using the click event and we use it to show only the completed tasks, `computed` is an option used to return data based on the changes of other properties

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
      tasks: [
          { description: "go to the store", completed: true },
          { description: "finish screencast", completed: false },
          { description: "make donation", completed: false },
          { description: "clear inbox", completed: false },
          { description: "make dinner ", completed: false },
          { description: "clean room", completed: true },
      ],
      onlyCompleted: false
  },
  methods: {
    hideIncompleteTasks() {
      this.onlyCompleted = !this.onlyCompleted
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.hiden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
      <h1>
          All Tasks
      </h1>
      <ul>
          <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task.description" :class="onlyCompleted && !task.completed && 'hiden' "></li>
      </ul>
      <button @click="hideIncompleteTasks">show only completed</button>

  </div>
```